# fieldset not fully displayed around the div

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am using fieldset to create titled border around div.

This is the code:

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-12">
        <fieldset class="field_set col-xs-12">
            <legend style="font-weight:bold;font-size:20px"> &nbsp;Sproc Details:</legend>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group col-xs-3">

                    <span>
                        Application Name <span></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
                    <span>
                        DB Name <span></span>
                    </span>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
                    <span>
                        Schema Name <span></span>
                    </span>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
                    <span>
                        Sproc Name <span></span>
                    </span>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group col-xs-3">

                    <span class="btn btn-block btn-success">
                        {{appName}} <span></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
                    <span class="btn btn-block btn-success">
                        {{dbName}} <span></span>
                    </span>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
                    <span class="btn btn-block btn-success">
                        {{schemaName}} <span></span>
                    </span>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
                    <span class="btn btn-block btn-success">
                        {{sprocName}} <span></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

The css for fieldset is :

```
   .field_set {
    border: 2px white solid;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

When I am executing this : 
I am receiving my output like this : 
[image]

As you can see, It is not fully displayed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that CSS code is for tags of the class field_set, but I haven't used CSS in a little while. Is that what you meant to use?

Comment: @Prakhar What is the expected output?

Comment: i want fieldset to be on top also..  like the border should surround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
<legend style="font-weight:bold;font-size:20px"> &nbsp;Sproc Details:</legend>
```

With:

```
<legend style="font-weight:bold;font-size:20px;width:8%;"> &nbsp;Sproc Details:</legend>
```

Comment: Also, can you tell, How can i make a common border around 3 divs without introducing a new line

Comment: The legend is taking the full width to create that effect so you need to change it to just 8% for example. I don't understand the second question.